# Rxjs Observer filter not working for error

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have the following code in my service

```
        let b = new BehaviorSubject({ a: undefined })
        let o = b.asObservable();
        o.pipe(filter(_ => _.a === 5)).subscribe(() => {
            debugger;
        }, error => {
            debugger
        })
        b.next({ a: 10 })
        b.next({ a: 5 })
        b.error({ a: 10 })
```

When I invoke b.next({a:10}) it does not hit the debugger in the onNext callback When I invoke b.next({a:5}) it hits the debugger in the onNext callback.
When I invoke b.error({a:10}) it hits the debugger in the onError callback.

My expectation was the onError callback should not be called since the filter condition was not satisfied. But, clearly I have something wrong here.

How do I filter the errors too?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: An observable can only error once. You can't send multiple error notifications. You can catch errors with `catchError` and  return an observable you want to switch to.

Comment: Thank you @fridoo that helps. Now I understand why it wont work the way I expected it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter `error`s for the same reason you can't filter `complete`s. It doesn't make sense. They signal the end of a stream. You can't filter the end.

You can, of course, catch an error and then do nothing - which feels a bit like filtering an error.

```
o.pipe(
  catchError(err => 
    err?.a === 5 ?
    return of(err) :
    EMPTY
  ),
  filter(val => val.a === 5)
).subscribe({
  next: val => debugger,
  error: err => debugger,
  complete: () => debugger
});
```

Of course, anything you send to the subject after you error or complete will do nothing.

```
    b.next({ a: 10 }); // Filtered, not emitted
    b.next({ a: 5 }); // value emitted
    b.error({ a: 5 }); // caught and new non-error { a: 5 } emitted as value. subject 'b' is done
    b.next({ a: 5 }); // Does nothing
```

That final call will do nothing as the subject has errored/completed.

Similarily:

```
    b.next({ a: 10 }); // Filtered, not emitted
    b.next({ a: 5 }); // value emitted
    b.complete(); // subject 'b' is done
    b.next({ a: 5 }); // Does nothing
```

Finally:

```
    b.next({ a: 10 }); // Filtered, not emitted
    b.next({ a: 5 }); // value emitted
    b.error({ a: 10 }); // caught and not emitted. subject 'b' is done
    b.next({ a: 5 }); // Does nothing
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the "It doesn't make sense" assessment in the accepted answer.
I found this question because I tried filtering in an interceptor that handles authentication errors *(and only those)* globally on all requests, but leaves actual application errors *(status codes other than 401)* to their respective error handlers.
For anyone looking at similar problems: instead of filtering, do

```
return throwError(() => err);
```

for the latter unhandled cases in your interceptor to forward it to the next error handler in the chain.